# How do I add attachments without replacing the old one?

Tags: c#, email

I'm working on a messaging software, I'm working on the Attachements part,
I can attach the files but, when I try to add more, it replaces the old ones.

This is the code:

```
List<string> listaAnexos = new List<string>();
Archivo.Multiselect = true;
Archivo.ShowDialog();
int cAnex = 0;
string[] anexos = Archivo.FileNames;

foreach (string i in anexos) 
{ 
    listaAnexos.Add(i);
    cAnex++;   
}
lbAnexos.DataSource = listaAnexos;
txtCAnex.Text = cAnex.ToString();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the above piece of code is called multiple times, you most likely need to declare `listaAnexos` outside of your method.

Every time you run the above method, you create a new instance of `listAnexos` to add files to, which you then assign to `lbAnexos.DataSource`, overwriting whatever was in there before.

Declare `listaAnexos` as a class instance, instead of inside your method.

```
public class YourClass
{
    private List<string> listaAnexos = new List<string>();

    private void YourMethod()
    {
        Archivo.Multiselect = true;
        Archivo.ShowDialog();

        ...

        foreach (string i in anexos) 
        { 
            listaAnexos.Add(i);
            ...
```

Comment: in case that i follow your advise, "Archivo" is a SaveFileDialog, and if the class is private, i cannot use the one that i create previously, so i will need to create a new one in the new class? (sorry for the problems im new to C#)